# suppress multiple function triggers with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I inherited an old laravel 4.2 codebase that I will be fixing up and migrating to latest version shortly.

In the meantime, there is one bug that needs fixing that is giving me a problem. There is a send mail routine that once triggered sends the same email 3 times...even though it should only send once. Is there a way to send the first email and not the other two? Kind of a cooldown timer?

Thanks!

Piece of code that sends the email

```
if ($send_emails == true) {
        Mail::send(
            'emails.event_notify',
            json_decode( json_encode( $data ), true ),
            function( $message ) use ($data, $subject, $emailList) {
                $message->to( $emailList );
                $message->from( "email@example.com" );
                $message->subject( $subject );
            }   
        );
    }
```

$emailList is a simple array of 3 emails in this case.

Comment: We're going to need the code that sends emails if you want help.

Comment: the question is, why does it sends 3 email? maybe that code is being called thrice?

Comment: nothing that I can find seems to call that three times though, thats the problem.

Comment: can you show us what your $emailList contains?

Comment: also check whether the if condition is not under any other loop.

Comment: not under any loop that i can find :(